# Sub Type Comparator One Liner Issue

Tags: java, list, sorting, reverse, one-liner

Why do I need a temporary variable as personAgentComparator needed here and to call reversed() on that?

```
public class SubTypeComparatorIssue {

  public void sortAgeFromOldToYoung(List<Person> persons) {
    //persons.sort(Comparator.comparing(person -> person.age).reversed());
      Comparator<Person> personAgeComparator = Comparator.comparing(person -> person.age);
      persons.sort(personAgeComparator.reversed());
  }
}

class Person {
  int age;
}
```

How do I get the sorting and reversing to with the comparator as a one-liner? I am getting an error in the lambda expression under `person.age` when currying the `reversed()` on that commented line.  If the reversed() is not added, I don't get that error even!  Hence did for now in two lines with that temporary `personAgentComparator` and called `reversed()` on it while calling the `sort()`.

Basically, how do I get a oneliner to do this whole operation?

I expect a correction on this line to have it as a oneliner to get the `persons` list reverse sorted by person's age.

```
persons.sort(Comparator.comparing(person -> person.age).reversed());
```

Comment: IIRC, the problem is that the type inference will breakdown across method invocations. I think it will work if you use `persons.sort(Comparator.<Person>comparing(person -> person.age).reversed());`

Comment: Or use a method instead of accessing the field, `persons.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getAge).reversed());`

Comment: You can also do it like this `persons.sort(Comparator.comparing((Person person) -> person.age).reversed());`

Comment: Forth option: `persons.sort(Collections.reverseOrder(Comparator.comparing(person -> person.age)));`.

Answer (score 0):

One of the way using lambda

`persons.sort((p1, p2) -> Integer.compare(p2.age, p1.age));`